# Custom Control Styling/Triggers Part II - Overriding Aero

Tags: wpf, templates, triggers, styles, mouseover

This is a follow-up to [Overriding button background in WPF on Aero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424699/overriding-button-background-in-wpf-on-aero) and to a minor degree [Custom Control Styling/Triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9622321/custom-control-styling-triggers).

In trying to keep the functionality of a ToggleButton but get rid of the button style, I followed the process of the first link above.  It basically works, albeit with a minor modification of changing the `RenderMouseOver` and `RenderPressed` to `false` (Otherwise it was sensing the mouse being over anywhere in the window, rather than just when over the `ToggleButton`.

So now my problem is, with the markup below, the `IsMouseOver` trigger doesn't change the background at all.  Any ideas from looking at the XAML?

On a side note, I was trying to use `BitmapEffect` to make the letters glow when toggled, but no matter what settings I use it doesn't seem to have an effect.  Anyone know of a guide that deals specifically with this?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:TimePicker}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Height}" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Width}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="Black"
                        BorderThickness="1">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                        <ToggleButton VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                                      Margin="0"
                                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                      BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                      Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Hour}">
                            <ToggleButton.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                    <Aero:ButtonChrome SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                                       Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                                       BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                                       RenderMouseOver="False"
                                                       RenderPressed="False">
                                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                                          />
                                    </Aero:ButtonChrome>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </ToggleButton.Template>
                            <ToggleButton.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />                                                
                                            <Setter Property="BitmapEffect">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <OuterGlowBitmapEffect GlowColor="Red" GlowSize="30" />
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </ToggleButton.Style>
                        </ToggleButton>
                        <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                               VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                               Content=":"/>
                        <ToggleButton VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                                      Margin="0"
                                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                      BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                      Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Minute}" />

                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be that the Background of your control is set to `{x:Null}` by default, try setting `<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>` {x:Null won't detect a mouse, Transparent will.

**Edit (addition):**

OverridesDefaultStyle = True should be in the style.setters not in the trigger.

Example:

```
<ToggleButton Content="ToggleButton" Height="30" Width="110" >
  <ToggleButton.Style>
    <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
      <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
      <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True"/>
      <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
      <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
      <Setter Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
          <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="0.48" Color="#DDDDDD"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="#CCCCCC"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="0.52" Color="#BBBBBB"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#CCCCCC"/>
          </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
          <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
            <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#DDDDDD"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="0.48" Color="#BBBBBB"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="#AAAAAA"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="0.52" Color="#999999"/>
            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#AAAAAA"/>
          </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
      <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    CornerRadius="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" UseLayoutRounding="{TemplateBinding UseLayoutRounding}">
              <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                  <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                  <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background">
                  <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                      <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
                      <GradientStop Offset="0.48" Color="#EEEEEE"/>
                      <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="#DDDDDD"/>
                      <GradientStop Offset="0.52" Color="#CCCCCC"/>
                      <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#DDDDDD"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                  </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
              </MultiTrigger>
              <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                  <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                  <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#666666"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2,2,1,1"/>
                <Setter Property="Background">
                  <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                      <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#AAAAAA"/>
                      <GradientStop Offset="0.48" Color="#999999"/>
                      <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="#AAAAAA"/>
                      <GradientStop Offset="0.52" Color="#BBBBBB"/>
                      <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#DDDDDD"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                  </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
              </MultiTrigger>
              <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                  <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                  <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#333333"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2,2,1,1"/>
                <Setter Property="Background">
                  <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                      <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#999999"/>
                      <GradientStop Offset="0.48" Color="#888888"/>
                      <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="#999999"/>
                      <GradientStop Offset="0.52" Color="#AAAAAA"/>
                      <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#CCCCCC"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                  </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
              </MultiTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

As for the glow:

Replace the ContentPresenter entirely with this:

```
          <Grid>
            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPart" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                              TextBlock.Foreground="#5588FF" Visibility="Collapsed">
              <ContentPresenter.Effect>
                <BlurEffect />
              </ContentPresenter.Effect>
            </ContentPresenter>
          </Grid>
```

and add this simple trigger:

```
<Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="ContentPart" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                  </Trigger>
```

Comment: Just tried it:  Didn't work.  I tried it on every background statement in there and nothing.  :)

Comment: If you are really interested in creating styles and controltemplates, than check out this site full of examples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752043.aspx I'v always avoided using the Themes provided like Areo and the other 5 or 6, because they don't teach you anything :)

Comment: I ran into 2 problems with this.  First, the OverridesDefaultStyle did not fix the background hover problem.  Secondly, in regards to the Blur Effect, VS won't let me set a TargetName within a style setter. I don't know if this matters, but this is inside of the generic.xaml file for the custom control.  Oh, and I really do greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Triggers hardly ever reside in the style, only setters regarding orientation and such properties go directly under the style tag, to be able to create more templates in one style. Most of the (effect-related) triggers are part of the controltemplate, so the blureffect trigger should also be added to the controltemplate, not to the styletag. If you copy the style that I'v presented you, than you will notice it changes it's background color on hover, even in checked state.

Comment: Well I played with it some more and finally got it working.  I did switch the triggers back over into the ControlTemplate, but I also went back and read through the first link posted above,  It seems I missed the part where the background cannot be setin the ToggleButton declaration, just in the style.  Thanks again for your help with this, and that glow effect is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to post the final markup for this, in case anybody ever is searching for the same thing.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:TimePicker}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Height}" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Width}" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="Transparent"
                        BorderThickness="1">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                        <ToggleButton VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                                      Margin="0"                                          
                                      BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                      BorderThickness="0"
                                      Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Hour}">
                            <ToggleButton.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                    <Aero:ButtonChrome SnapsToDevicePixels="True"                                                           
                                                       Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                                       BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"                                                           
                                                       RenderDefaulted="False">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPart"
                                                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                                              TextBlock.Foreground="#FF605c" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                                <ContentPresenter.Effect>
                                                    <BlurEffect />
                                                </ContentPresenter.Effect>
                                            </ContentPresenter>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Aero:ButtonChrome>
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                            <Setter TargetName="ContentPart" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                                            <Setter TargetName="ContentPart" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />                                                
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </ToggleButton.Template>
                            <ToggleButton.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                                </Style>
                            </ToggleButton.Style>
                        </ToggleButton>
                        <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"
                               VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                               Content=":"/>
                        <ToggleButton VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                                      Margin="0"
                                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                      BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                      Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Minute}" />

                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Just discovered one other thing:  If you delete the `<Aero:...` sections above, everything else still works, AND it gets rid of the white InnerBorder that Aero so nicely forces on us.